# NSOperation to manage series of functions

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift

I have multiple functions which should be happening in order. And `function1` and `function3` run in back thread. Their functions are `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`. `Function 2` can be happening on main thread or on back thread, but it should run after `function 1` and `function 3` should happen right after `function2`. I got to know about `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` but I'm not sure how to really use it. Based on what I researched, I can only make class to subclass `NSOperation`. Is this correct? I would like to make each functions to be under `NSOpeation`. Below is the way I think to be correct. Is this right way to approach? And is it correct to put function1() inside of `NSOperation` like below? Lastly, does it affect `NSOperationQueue` when some functions are happening in back thread like `function 1 & 3` ?  Thank you

```
var operationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
let operation1 : NSOperation = NSOperation(function1())
let operation2 : NSOperation = NSOperation(function2())
let operation3 : NSOperation = NSOperation(function3())

operation2.addDependency(operation1)
operation3.addDependency(operation2)

operationQueue.addOperation(operation1)
operationQueue.addOperation(operation2)
operationQueue.addOperation(operation3)        

func function1 () {
//do something and save data in this class's property
}

func function2 () {
//get data from class's property(data from function1) and do something
//save the result in class's property
}

func function3 () {
  //get data from class's property(data from function2) and do something
 //save the result in class's property
}
```

Comment: Use Block Operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an NSBlockOperation to wrap a block, like this:

```
    let operationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

    let operation1 = NSBlockOperation {
        // body of function 1
    }

    let operation2 = NSBlockOperation {
        // or call function 2
    }

    operation2.addDependency(operation1)

    operationQueue.addOperation(operation1)
    operationQueue.addOperation(operation2)
```

Also, you can directly enqueue blocks on the queue:

```
    operationQueue.addOperationWithBlock {
        // body of function 3
    }
```

The drawback is you don't have access to the operation so you can't set up dependencies.

Comment: Thank you! I do not get the part that i cannot set up dependencies when you wrote "addDependency" there. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: This approach will not work when the three functions, themselves, are asynchronous.

Comment: @Kahsn - His point was that if you use `addOperationWithBlock` you cannot use dependencies (because `addOperationWithBlock` creates operation and adds it to the queue, but never returns the `NSOperation` reference that you need for `addDependency`). But if you use the `NSBlockOperation`, it works fine (but only if the functions run synchronously).

Answer (score 2):

In order for dependencies to work correctly when your functions are, themselves, performing asynchronous operations, you have to:

- subclass `NSOperation`;
- make sure the [`asynchronous`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSOperation/asynchronous) property returns `true`; and
- perform the necessary `isExecuting` and `isFinished` KVO.

Also, when implementing asynchronous operations, you also should:

- implement cancelation logic that does more than just flag the operation as complete, but also stops any request that might be in progress.

For an example of concurrent/asynchronous operations with `NSURLSession`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27022598/1271826. The principles outlined there would apply here, too.