# How To Download Multiple Files Sequentially using URLSession downloadTask in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, nsoperation, urlsession

I have an app that has to download multiple large files. I want it to download each file one by one sequentially instead of concurrently. When it runs concurrently, the app gets overloaded and crashes.

So. I’m trying to wrap a `downloadTask` inside a `BlockOperation` and then setting the `maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1` on the queue. I wrote this code below but it didn’t work since both files get downloaded concurrently.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDownloadDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        processURLs()
    }

    func download(url: URL) {
        let session: URLSession = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
        let downloadTask = session.downloadTask(with: URLRequest(url: url))
        downloadTask.resume()
    }

    func processURLs(){
        //setup queue and set max concurrent to 1
        var queue = OperationQueue()
        queue.name = "Download queue"
        queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1

        let url = URL(string: "http://azspeastus.blob.core.windows.net/azurespeed/100MB.bin?sv=2014-02-14&sr=b&sig=%2FZNzdvvzwYO%2BQUbrLBQTalz%2F8zByvrUWD%2BDfLmkpZuQ%3D&se=2015-09-01T01%3A48%3A51Z&sp=r")
        let url2 = URL(string: "http://azspwestus.blob.core.windows.net/azurespeed/100MB.bin?sv=2014-02-14&sr=b&sig=ufnzd4x9h1FKmLsODfnbiszXd4EyMDUJgWhj48QfQ9A%3D&se=2015-09-01T01%3A48%3A51Z&sp=r")

        let urls = [url, url2].compactMap { $0 }
        for url in urls {
            let operation = BlockOperation {
                print("starting download")
                self.download(url: url)
            }

            queue.addOperation(operation)
        }
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        …
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didResumeAtOffset fileOffset: Int64, expectedTotalBytes: Int64) {
        …
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
        var progress = Double(totalBytesWritten) / Double(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
        print(progress)
    }
}
```

How can I write this properly to achieve my goal of only downloading one file at a time?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Your code won't work because `URLSessionDownloadTask` runs asynchronously. Thus the `BlockOperation` completes before the download is done and therefore while the operations fire off sequentially, the download tasks will continue asynchronously and in parallel.

While there are work-arounds one can contemplate (e.g., recursive patterns initiating one request after the prior one finishes, non-zero semaphore pattern on background thread, etc.), the elegant solution is one of the proven asynchronous frameworks.

In iOS 15 and later, we would use `async`-`await` method [`download(from:delegate:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/3767355-download/), e.g.

```swift
func downloadFiles() async throws {
    let folder = try! FileManager.default
        .url(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

    for url in urls {
        let (source, _) = try await URLSession.shared.download(from: url)
        let destination = folder.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
        try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: source, to: destination)
    }
}
```

Where

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Task {
        do {
            try await downloadFiles()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

That only works in iOS 15 and later (or macOS 12 and later). But Xcode 13.2 and later actually lets you use async-await in iOS 13, but you just have to write your own `async` rendition of `download`. See [Cancelling an async/await Network Request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70416311/1271826) for sample implementation. And you would then call this rendition for iOS 13 and later:

```swift
func downloadFiles() async throws {
    let folder = try! FileManager.default
        .url(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

    for url in urls {
        let (source, _) = try await URLSession.shared.download(with: url)
        let destination = folder.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
        try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: source, to: destination)
    }
}
```

---

In iOS versions prior to 13, if you wanted to control the degree of concurrency of a series of asynchronous tasks, we would reach for an asynchronous [`Operation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation) subclass.

Or, in iOS 13 and later, you might also consider [Combine](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine). (There are other third-party asynchronous programming frameworks, but I will restrict myself to Apple-provided approaches.)

Both of these are described below in my original answer.

---

**Operation**

To address this, you can wrap the requests in asynchronous [`Operation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation) subclass. See [Configuring Operations for Concurrent Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW8) in the *Concurrency Programming Guide* for more information.

But before I illustrate how to do this in your situation (the delegate-based `URLSession`), let me first show you the simpler solution when using the completion handler rendition. We'll later build upon this for your more complicated question. So, in Swift 3 and later:

```
class DownloadOperation : AsynchronousOperation {
    var task: URLSessionTask!
    
    init(session: URLSession, url: URL) {
        super.init()
        
        task = session.downloadTask(with: url) { temporaryURL, response, error in
            defer { self.finish() }
            
            guard
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                200..<300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode
            else {
                // handle invalid return codes however you'd like
                return
            }

            guard let temporaryURL = temporaryURL, error == nil else {
                print(error ?? "Unknown error")
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let manager = FileManager.default
                let destinationURL = try manager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
                    .appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
                try? manager.removeItem(at: destinationURL)                   // remove the old one, if any
                try manager.moveItem(at: temporaryURL, to: destinationURL)    // move new one there
            } catch let moveError {
                print("\(moveError)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func cancel() {
        task.cancel()
        super.cancel()
    }
    
    override func main() {
        task.resume()
    }
    
}
```

Where

```
/// Asynchronous operation base class
///
/// This is abstract to class emits all of the necessary KVO notifications of `isFinished`
/// and `isExecuting` for a concurrent `Operation` subclass. You can subclass this and
/// implement asynchronous operations. All you must do is:
///
/// - override `main()` with the tasks that initiate the asynchronous task;
///
/// - call `completeOperation()` function when the asynchronous task is done;
///
/// - optionally, periodically check `self.cancelled` status, performing any clean-up
///   necessary and then ensuring that `finish()` is called; or
///   override `cancel` method, calling `super.cancel()` and then cleaning-up
///   and ensuring `finish()` is called.

class AsynchronousOperation: Operation {
    
    /// State for this operation.
    
    @objc private enum OperationState: Int {
        case ready
        case executing
        case finished
    }
    
    /// Concurrent queue for synchronizing access to `state`.
    
    private let stateQueue = DispatchQueue(label: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + ".rw.state", attributes: .concurrent)
    
    /// Private backing stored property for `state`.
    
    private var rawState: OperationState = .ready
    
    /// The state of the operation
    
    @objc private dynamic var state: OperationState {
        get { return stateQueue.sync { rawState } }
        set { stateQueue.sync(flags: .barrier) { rawState = newValue } }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Various `Operation` properties
    
    open         override var isReady:        Bool { return state == .ready && super.isReady }
    public final override var isExecuting:    Bool { return state == .executing }
    public final override var isFinished:     Bool { return state == .finished }
    
    // KVO for dependent properties
    
    open override class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey key: String) -> Set<String> {
        if ["isReady", "isFinished", "isExecuting"].contains(key) {
            return [#keyPath(state)]
        }
        
        return super.keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey: key)
    }
    
    // Start
    
    public final override func start() {
        if isCancelled {
            finish()
            return
        }
        
        state = .executing
        
        main()
    }
    
    /// Subclasses must implement this to perform their work and they must not call `super`. The default implementation of this function throws an exception.
    
    open override func main() {
        fatalError("Subclasses must implement `main`.")
    }
    
    /// Call this function to finish an operation that is currently executing
    
    public final func finish() {
        if !isFinished { state = .finished }
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
for url in urls {
    queue.addOperation(DownloadOperation(session: session, url: url))
}
```

So that's one very easy way to wrap asynchronous `URLSession`/`NSURLSession` requests in asynchronous `Operation`/`NSOperation` subclass. More generally, this is a useful pattern, using `AsynchronousOperation` to wrap up some asynchronous task in an `Operation`/`NSOperation` object.

Unfortunately, in your question, you wanted to use delegate-based `URLSession`/`NSURLSession` so you could monitor the progress of the downloads. This is more complicated.

This is because the "task complete" `NSURLSession` delegate methods are called at the session object's delegate. This is an infuriating design feature of `NSURLSession` (but Apple did it to simplify background sessions, which isn't relevant here, but we're stuck with that design limitation).

But we have to asynchronously complete the operations as the tasks finish. So we need some way for the session to figure out which operation to complete when `didCompleteWithError` is called. Now you could have each operation have its own `NSURLSession` object, but it turns out that this is pretty inefficient.

So, to handle that, I maintain a dictionary, keyed by the task's `taskIdentifier`, which identifies the appropriate operation. That way, when the download finishes, you can "complete" the correct asynchronous operation. Thus:

```
/// Manager of asynchronous download `Operation` objects

class DownloadManager: NSObject {
    
    /// Dictionary of operations, keyed by the `taskIdentifier` of the `URLSessionTask`
    
    fileprivate var operations = [Int: DownloadOperation]()
    
    /// Serial OperationQueue for downloads
    
    private let queue: OperationQueue = {
        let _queue = OperationQueue()
        _queue.name = "download"
        _queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1    // I'd usually use values like 3 or 4 for performance reasons, but OP asked about downloading one at a time
        
        return _queue
    }()
    
    /// Delegate-based `URLSession` for DownloadManager
    
    lazy var session: URLSession = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        return URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    }()
    
    /// Add download
    ///
    /// - parameter URL:  The URL of the file to be downloaded
    ///
    /// - returns:        The DownloadOperation of the operation that was queued
    
    @discardableResult
    func queueDownload(_ url: URL) -> DownloadOperation {
        let operation = DownloadOperation(session: session, url: url)
        operations[operation.task.taskIdentifier] = operation
        queue.addOperation(operation)
        return operation
    }
    
    /// Cancel all queued operations
    
    func cancelAll() {
        queue.cancelAllOperations()
    }
    
}

// MARK: URLSessionDownloadDelegate methods

extension DownloadManager: URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        operations[downloadTask.taskIdentifier]?.urlSession(session, downloadTask: downloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo: location)
    }
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
        operations[downloadTask.taskIdentifier]?.urlSession(session, downloadTask: downloadTask, didWriteData: bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten: totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
    }
}

// MARK: URLSessionTaskDelegate methods

extension DownloadManager: URLSessionTaskDelegate {
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)  {
        let key = task.taskIdentifier
        operations[key]?.urlSession(session, task: task, didCompleteWithError: error)
        operations.removeValue(forKey: key)
    }
    
}

/// Asynchronous Operation subclass for downloading

class DownloadOperation : AsynchronousOperation {
    let task: URLSessionTask
    
    init(session: URLSession, url: URL) {
        task = session.downloadTask(with: url)
        super.init()
    }
    
    override func cancel() {
        task.cancel()
        super.cancel()
    }
    
    override func main() {
        task.resume()
    }
}

// MARK: NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate methods

extension DownloadOperation: URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        guard
            let httpResponse = downloadTask.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            200..<300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode
        else {
            // handle invalid return codes however you'd like
            return
        }

        do {
            let manager = FileManager.default
            let destinationURL = try manager
                .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
                .appendingPathComponent(downloadTask.originalRequest!.url!.lastPathComponent)
            try? manager.removeItem(at: destinationURL)
            try manager.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationURL)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
        let progress = Double(totalBytesWritten) / Double(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
        print("\(downloadTask.originalRequest!.url!.absoluteString) \(progress)")
    }
}

// MARK: URLSessionTaskDelegate methods

extension DownloadOperation: URLSessionTaskDelegate {
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)  {
        defer { finish() }
        
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        
        // do whatever you want upon success
    }
    
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
let downloadManager = DownloadManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let urlStrings = [
        "http://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/images/apollo/apollo17/hires/s72-55482.jpg",
        "http://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/images/apollo/apollo10/hires/as10-34-5162.jpg",
        "http://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/images/apollo-soyuz/apollo-soyuz/hires/s75-33375.jpg",
        "http://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/images/apollo/apollo17/hires/as17-134-20380.jpg",
        "http://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/images/apollo/apollo17/hires/as17-140-21497.jpg",
        "http://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/images/apollo/apollo17/hires/as17-148-22727.jpg"
    ]
    let urls = urlStrings.compactMap { URL(string: $0) }
    
    let completion = BlockOperation {
        print("all done")
    }
    
    for url in urls {
        let operation = downloadManager.queueDownload(url)
        completion.addDependency(operation)
    }

    OperationQueue.main.addOperation(completion)
}
```

See [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32322851/4) for Swift 2 implementation.

---

**Combine**

For [Combine](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine), the idea would be to create a `Publisher` for `URLSessionDownloadTask`. Then you can do something like:

```
var downloadRequests: AnyCancellable?

/// Download a series of assets

func downloadAssets() {
    downloadRequests = downloadsPublisher(for: urls, maxConcurrent: 1).sink { completion in
        switch completion {
        case .finished:
            print("done")

        case .failure(let error):
            print("failed", error)
        }
    } receiveValue: { destinationUrl in
        print(destinationUrl)
    }
}

/// Publisher for single download
///
/// Copy downloaded resource to caches folder.
///
/// - Parameter url: `URL` being downloaded.
/// - Returns: Publisher for the URL with final destination of the downloaded asset.

func downloadPublisher(for url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<URL, Error> {
    URLSession.shared.downloadTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .tryCompactMap {
            let destination = try FileManager.default
                .url(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
                .appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
            try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: $0.location, to: destination)
            return destination
        }
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

/// Publisher for a series of downloads
///
/// This downloads not more than `maxConcurrent` assets at a given time.
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - urls: Array of `URL`s of assets to be downloaded.
///   - maxConcurrent: The maximum number of downloads to run at any given time (default 4).
/// - Returns: Publisher for the URLs with final destination of the downloaded assets.

func downloadsPublisher(for urls: [URL], maxConcurrent: Int = 4) -> AnyPublisher<URL, Error> {
    Publishers.Sequence(sequence: urls.map { downloadPublisher(for: $0) })
        .flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(maxConcurrent)) { $0 }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Now, unfortunately, Apple supplies a `DataTaskPublisher` (which loads the full asset into memory which is not acceptable solution for large assets), but one can refer to [their source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/88b093e9d77d6201935a2c2fb13f27d961836777/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/Publishers%2BURLSession.swift) and adapt it to create a `DownloadTaskPublisher`:

```
//  DownloadTaskPublisher.swift
//
//  Created by Robert Ryan on 9/28/20.
//
//  Adapted from Apple's `DataTaskPublisher` at:
//  https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/88b093e9d77d6201935a2c2fb13f27d961836777/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/Publishers%2BURLSession.swift

import Foundation
import Combine

// MARK: Download Tasks

@available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
extension URLSession {
    /// Returns a publisher that wraps a URL session download task for a given URL.
    ///
    /// The publisher publishes temporary when the task completes, or terminates if the task fails with an error.
    ///
    /// - Parameter url: The URL for which to create a download task.
    /// - Returns: A publisher that wraps a download task for the URL.

    public func downloadTaskPublisher(for url: URL) -> DownloadTaskPublisher {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        return DownloadTaskPublisher(request: request, session: self)
    }

    /// Returns a publisher that wraps a URL session download task for a given URL request.
    ///
    /// The publisher publishes download when the task completes, or terminates if the task fails with an error.
    ///
    /// - Parameter request: The URL request for which to create a download task.
    /// - Returns: A publisher that wraps a download task for the URL request.

    public func downloadTaskPublisher(for request: URLRequest) -> DownloadTaskPublisher {
        return DownloadTaskPublisher(request: request, session: self)
    }

    public struct DownloadTaskPublisher: Publisher {
        public typealias Output = (location: URL, response: URLResponse)
        public typealias Failure = URLError

        public let request: URLRequest
        public let session: URLSession

        public init(request: URLRequest, session: URLSession) {
            self.request = request
            self.session = session
        }

        public func receive<S: Subscriber>(subscriber: S) where Failure == S.Failure, Output == S.Input {
            subscriber.receive(subscription: Inner(self, subscriber))
        }

        private typealias Parent = DownloadTaskPublisher
        private final class Inner<Downstream: Subscriber>: Subscription, CustomStringConvertible, CustomReflectable, CustomPlaygroundDisplayConvertible
        where
            Downstream.Input == Parent.Output,
            Downstream.Failure == Parent.Failure
        {
            typealias Input = Downstream.Input
            typealias Failure = Downstream.Failure

            private let lock: NSLocking
            private var parent: Parent?               // GuardedBy(lock)
            private var downstream: Downstream?       // GuardedBy(lock)
            private var demand: Subscribers.Demand    // GuardedBy(lock)
            private var task: URLSessionDownloadTask! // GuardedBy(lock)
            var description: String { return "DownloadTaskPublisher" }
            var customMirror: Mirror {
                lock.lock()
                defer { lock.unlock() }
                return Mirror(self, children: [
                    "task": task as Any,
                    "downstream": downstream as Any,
                    "parent": parent as Any,
                    "demand": demand,
                ])
            }
            var playgroundDescription: Any { return description }

            init(_ parent: Parent, _ downstream: Downstream) {
                self.lock = NSLock()
                self.parent = parent
                self.downstream = downstream
                self.demand = .max(0)
            }

            // MARK: - Upward Signals
            func request(_ d: Subscribers.Demand) {
                precondition(d > 0, "Invalid request of zero demand")

                lock.lock()
                guard let p = parent else {
                    // We've already been cancelled so bail
                    lock.unlock()
                    return
                }

                // Avoid issues around `self` before init by setting up only once here
                if self.task == nil {
                    let task = p.session.downloadTask(
                        with: p.request,
                        completionHandler: handleResponse(location:response:error:)
                    )
                    self.task = task
                }

                self.demand += d
                let task = self.task!
                lock.unlock()

                task.resume()
            }

            private func handleResponse(location: URL?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) {
                lock.lock()
                guard demand > 0,
                      parent != nil,
                      let ds = downstream
                else {
                    lock.unlock()
                    return
                }

                parent = nil
                downstream = nil

                // We clear demand since this is a single shot shape
                demand = .max(0)
                task = nil
                lock.unlock()

                if let location = location, let response = response, error == nil {
                    _ = ds.receive((location, response))
                    ds.receive(completion: .finished)
                } else {
                    let urlError = error as? URLError ?? URLError(.unknown)
                    ds.receive(completion: .failure(urlError))
                }
            }

            func cancel() {
                lock.lock()
                guard parent != nil else {
                    lock.unlock()
                    return
                }
                parent = nil
                downstream = nil
                demand = .max(0)
                let task = self.task
                self.task = nil
                lock.unlock()
                task?.cancel()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, unfortunately, that isn’t using `URLSession` delegate pattern, but rather the completion handler rendition. But one could conceivably adapt it for delegate pattern.

Also, this will stop downloads when one fails. If you don't want it to stop just because one fails, you could conceivably define it to `Never` fail, and instead `replaceError` with `nil`:

```
/// Publisher for single download
///
/// Copy downloaded resource to caches folder.
///
/// - Parameter url: `URL` being downloaded.
/// - Returns: Publisher for the URL with final destination of the downloaded asset. Returns `nil` if request failed.

func downloadPublisher(for url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<URL?, Never> {
    URLSession.shared.downloadTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .tryCompactMap {
            let destination = try FileManager.default
                .url(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
                .appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
            try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: $0.location, to: destination)
            return destination
        }
        .replaceError(with: nil)
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

/// Publisher for a series of downloads
///
/// This downloads not more than `maxConcurrent` assets at a given time.
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - urls: Array of `URL`s of assets to be downloaded.
///   - maxConcurrent: The maximum number of downloads to run at any given time (default 4).
/// - Returns: Publisher for the URLs with final destination of the downloaded assets.

func downloadsPublisher(for urls: [URL], maxConcurrent: Int = 4) -> AnyPublisher<URL?, Never> {
    Publishers.Sequence(sequence: urls.map { downloadPublisher(for: $0) })
        .flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(maxConcurrent)) { $0 }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

---

Perhaps needless to say, I would generally discourage the downloading of assets/files sequentially. You should allow them to run concurrently, but control the degree of concurrency so your app is not overloaded. All of the patterns outlined above constrain the degree of concurrency to something reasonable.

Comment: BTW, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27022598/1271826) shows how to wrap Alamofire request in asynchronous operation. The pattern is similar when wrapping `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` requests, too. Also, FYI, this `NSOperation` technique does not work when dealing with background sessions. In those cases, you have to go old school, initiating the next request in the completion handler of the other request.

Comment: i never got this to work but ill accept this as the right answer.

Comment: @CraigH - I've expanded my answer, showing you how you would do this. I hesitated to include all of this in my original answer, because it's a bit much, but given you had problems implementing this (which I'm entirely sympathetic to ... this is complicated), I've added relevant code samples.

Comment: Wow! What a mind-blowing answer. It gives you the entire logic behind how you can download multiple files simultaneously. It does not mean that you could not do this in another way, but the logic will be the same.

Comment: @Burak - Lol. Agreed, this code lets you run operations with whatever degree of concurrency you want. But if you do this on serial queue, you get the OP's desired consecutive behavior.

Comment: Can we pause and resume the downloads in the queue ?

Comment: How to pass the progress to a UIProgressView?

Comment: @Rob The "infuriating design feature" is especially acute with regard to data tasks. If you have a delegate, the delegate must keep receiving data chunks and doling them out into piles corresponding to the task. The problem is that there is only _one_ session and _many_ tasks but only _one_ delegate — the delegate is per session, not per task. In my opinion this vitiates the entire delegate architecture. If we use the completion handler approach, we get one completion handler per task, so why don't delegates work that way? I have good workarounds for all that, but it's still maddening.

Comment: @matt - I agree on all counts. Re why they did it this way, I would guess they did it this way because background sessions would be significantly more complicated if, when you reinstantiated the session, every task needed its own delegate. But I don't like their solution because, as you say, when doing foreground data tasks, this architecture is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @Rob thanks for the confirmation, I really appreciate it. Odd how they never acknowledge this issue in examples or videos (or do they?).

Comment: @matt - No, I don’t recall them bringing to our attention. Note, there is a kludgy work-around of having a separate session for every data task, which is tempting, but it introduces more memory overhead, which is why I didn’t do that above.

Comment: In the WWDC videos they basically beg us not to do that. :)

Comment: @Rob, Thank you for this code, it works perfectly. However I can't find a way to use the progress variable in the extension in the main class in order to use it with a custom progress view. would you mind explaining how to pass this variable?

Comment: Is it possible to pause and resume the downloads randomly in the queue ?

Comment: @Rob Please explain what is `BlockOperation ` here ?

Comment: @VarunNaharia - A [`BlockOperation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/blockoperation) is an Operation object that wraps a closure (and what we now call “closures” in Swift, used to be called “blocks” in Objective-C, hence the `BlockOperation` name). So a `BlockOperation` is just a way of saying “here is a bit of code that I will later add to some operation queue.” If you’re familiar with `DispatchWorkItem` in GCD, a `BlockOperation` is the operation queue equivalent.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but can you explain acronym KVN used in comments? I've never seen that and am having trouble understanding how it is different from KVO.

Comment: No worries. I’m talking KVO. But this isn’t the observing code, but rather the code to ensure that the appropriate key-value notifications got sent. Regardless, I’ve adjusted this to use the standard KVO acronym to eliminate any confusion.

Comment: @Rob in your answer how do we determine whether the downloaded file is proper and not any html file showing the errors like 404. How can we check that?


Say suppose I am downloading png from `www.test.com/test.png` as this url is invalid it will show html output in the web, `URLSessionDownloadTask` will download the html file and save it as .png

How can we prevent this?

Comment: @AnirudhaMahale - Check the status codes of the response. I’ve added some relevant guard statements above.

Comment: @Rob Could you maybe explain, how it would be possible to keep track of the overall progress? Would be much appreciated!

Comment: Bottom line, @finebel, you would generally want to use `Progress` objects for each download. In iOS 15 w `async`-`await`, it's pretty simple (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70396188/1271826). With traditional `URLSession` `downloadTask`, it's more complicated, because to get progress for individual downloads requires the delegate-based method (no progress is provided for completion-handler-based methods).

Comment: I don't work on the project anymore, but anyway - thanks for your reply :-)

Comment: @Rob in your Xcode 13.2 version, if I were to 1) have a *singleton* that had a property for *urls*, 2) your download method gets called via that *urls* property using *didSet*, and 3) in different vcs I was to add multiple urls to the singleton's urls property, would the download's `async-await` code run concurrently or consecutively? I ran into the same problem as the OP, I'm using `urlSession` via a singleton, and having all of those urlSessions running/returning at the same time makes my app hang. I wonder would your code prevent it but your code is only called once in 1 vc.

Comment: First, whether you use a singleton or not is immaterial. (IMHO, a singleton, while convenient, seems dubious.) Second, if you’re adding URL’s after the fact, I wouldn’t use a `didSet` observer, but an asynchronous sequence (probably beyond the scope of this question). Third, if you have a `for` loop that does an `await` of the prior request, then that’s going to be sequential. Fourth, if you have an app that is hanging, then that is something unrelated, unrelated to Swift concurrency. Feels like you should post your own question.

Comment: @Rob, thanks for the response. The hanging was video related. I filed a TSI with Apple and amazingly the issue which caused the videos to pause/hang didn’t occur on the Apple Engineer’s end, it only seemed to happen on my end. Long story short I was using an older version of Xcode (the engineer suggested to update my Xcode because he couldn’t reproduce the issue) and the multiple url requests was somehow causing the problem. I’ll post a more detailed question of the problem using multiple URLSessions and maybe add a link to this as a possible solution. Appreciate the response. Cheers!!

Comment: @Rob, I have implemented your solution with `Operation` and it's working fine for sequential download. But when i try to cancel the ongoing operation (which is executing), it seems the queue is stopped and nothing happens after that. Even there is no log in the console. Could you please shed some light? Thanks.

Comment: @Rob great answer. Q: what if I have 1000 links? How to download eg 3 files at the same time and when one is ready then proceed with the next one? Assuming I’m using iOS16 and up

Comment: @breq - It depends upon which of the many approaches I outlined above you are considering. But in Swift concurrency, you might use a task group with a `group.next()` call if the index exceeds a certain value. See the `DownloadManager` example in the latter part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73072799/1271826).

Comment: @breq - By the way, if you really had 1000 downloads, that really suggests a completely different approach, namely a background `URLSession`, one that will continue to execute when the user leaves the app. That renders the above patterns moot. E.g., in UIKit, see [Downloading Files in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background/).

Answer (score 2):

Here is rather minimalistic and pure-swift approach. With no NSOperationQueue(), just didSet-observer

```
    import Foundation


    class DownloadManager {

        var delegate: HavingWebView?
        var gotFirstAndEnough = true
        var finalURL: NSURL?{
            didSet{
                if finalURL != nil {
                    if let s = self.contentOfURL{
                        self.delegate?.webView.loadHTMLString(s, baseURL: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        var lastRequestBeginning: NSDate?

        var myLinks = [String](){
            didSet{
                self.handledLink = self.myLinks.count
            }
        }

        var contentOfURL: String?

        var handledLink = 0 {
            didSet{
                if handledLink == 0 {
                    self.finalURL = nil
                    print("")
                } else {
                    if self.finalURL == nil {
                        if let nextURL = NSURL(string: self.myLinks[self.handledLink-1]) {
                            self.loadAsync(nextURL)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        func loadAsync(url: NSURL) {
            let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration()
            let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 15.0)
            request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
            print("")
            self.lastRequestBeginning = NSDate()
            print("Requet began:    \(self.lastRequestBeginning )")
            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if (error == nil) {
                    if let response = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                        print("\(response)")
                        if response.statusCode == 200 {
                            if let content = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                                self.contentOfURL = content
                            }
                            self.finalURL =  url
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    print("Failure: \(error!.localizedDescription)");
                }

                let elapsed = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(self.lastRequestBeginning!)
                print("trying \(url) takes \(elapsed)")
                print("   Request finished")
                print("____________________________________________")
                self.handledLink -= 1
            })
            task.resume()
        }
    }
```

In ViewController:

```
protocol HavingWebView {
    var webView: UIWebView! {get set}
}


class ViewController: UIViewController, HavingWebView {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let dm = DownloadManager()
        dm.delegate = self
        dm.myLinks =  ["https://medium.com/the-mission/consider-the-present-and-future-value-of-your-decisions-b20fb72f5e#.a12uiiz11",
                       "https://medium.com/@prianka.kariat/ios-10-notifications-with-attachments-and-much-more-169a7405ddaf#.svymi6230",
                       "https://blog.medium.com/39-reasons-we-wont-soon-forget-2016-154ac95683af#.cmb37i58b",
                       "https://backchannel.com/in-2017-your-coworkers-will-live-everywhere-ae14979b5255#.wmi6hxk9p"]
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rob's answer has shown a right way to do this.
I achieved it the **delegate-based** way to track the download with a progress view.

You can check out the source code here.
[Multiple download with progress bar (Github)](https://github.com/toka756/MultipleDownload)

Answer (score 0):

More than one code in the background situation. I can learn by used global variable and NSTimer. You can try too.

Define 'indexDownloaded' global variable.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

private let _sharedUpdateStatus = UpdateStatus()
class UpdateStatus : NSObject  {

// MARK: - SHARED INSTANCE
class var shared : UpdateStatus {
    return _sharedUpdateStatus
}
  var indexDownloaded = 0
}
```

This code add in the DownloadOperation class.

```
print("⬇️" + URL.lastPathComponent! + " downloaded")
        UpdateStatus.shared.indexDownloaded += 1
        print(String(UpdateStatus.shared.indexDownloaded) + "\\" + String(UpdateStatus.shared.count))
```

This function in your viewController.

```
func startTimeAction () {
    let urlStrings = [
    "http://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/images/apollo/apollo17/hires/s72-55482.jpg",
    "http://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/images/apollo/apollo10/hires/as10-34-5162.jpg",
    "http://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/images/apollo-soyuz/apollo-soyuz/hires/s75-33375.jpg",
    "http://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/images/apollo/apollo17/hires/as17-134-20380.jpg",
    "http://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/images/apollo/apollo17/hires/as17-140-21497.jpg",
    "http://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/images/apollo/apollo17/hires/as17-148-22727.jpg"
    ]
    let urls = urlStrings.flatMap { URL(string: $0) }

    for url in urls {
       queue.addOperation(DownloadOperation(session: session, url: url))
    }

    UpdateStatus.shared.count = urls.count
     progressView.setProgress(0.0, animated: false)
    timer.invalidate()
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(timeAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func timeAction() {
    if UpdateStatus.shared.count != 0 {
        let set: Float = Float(UpdateStatus.shared.indexDownloaded) / Float(UpdateStatus.shared.count)

        progressView.setProgress(set, animated: true)
    }
```

in this way, by updating the progressview will look at the number of downloaded each time the timer runs.

Answer (score -9):

Objective-C version is:

```
[operation2 addDependency:operation1]
```

Comment: More importantly, using dependencies is no better than using `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of `1` on the queue when dealing with asynchronous tasks.