# How to get the download progress from resuming download data with await URLSession.shared.download(resumeFrom: data)

Tags: swift, async-await

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70396188/10865324) explains eloquently how to get download progress from a regular async/await download. How can I get the same progress from a resumed Data download using the `URLSession.shared.download(resumeFrom: data)` call?

Comment: You would have to use `downloadTask` to get progress. The attached link works because the result is an `AsyncSequence`. You can easily turn `downloadTask` into an `AsyncStream`

Comment: @loremipsum - I don’t think it is quite as simple as that linked `bytes`-based solution. I think if you want to get progress updates on `downloadTask` with “resume data”, you would have to create a delegate-based `URLSession` and then use the delegate-based rendition of `downloadTask`. Right? Sure, you could wrap that in an `AsyncSequence`, but it is a bit awkward (as you probably want a different sequence for each separate download being updated on that one delegate). I really wish we could specify separate task delegates for each download, without having separate sessions.

Comment: @Rob the delegate gives you a `dataTask` to be able to tell the difference between tasks. I think the hardest part is being prepared to call `cancel(byProducingResumeData:)` again if needed, it can't be done effectively in `onTermination`. But if there is no expectation of needing a second set of resumed data making a stream from a delegate is not an issue.