Do you need weak self in the closure of a data task?
Say you have
extension APISingleton {

    func items (
        _ blah: Blah?,
        completionOnMain: ( (_ status: Int, _ found: Blahs) -> ())? = nil
    ) {
        let t = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: r) { [weak self] (d, r, r) in
             guard let self else { ..; return }
             blah
             self.blah
             DispatchQueue.main.async { completionOnMain?(666, []) }
             blah
             DispatchQueue.main.async { completionOnMain?(200, parsed) }

        }
        p = task.progress.etc {NB, p is held somewhere}
        t.resume()
    }

    func refunds ( ... other similar api calls
}

and you call it from anywhere, perhaps a VC, as
api.items(thisUser) { .. etc
    // note, obviously you use weak self here in the VC
    // this, obviously, is not what the question is about TY
    foldin(stuff: found)
}

I have always checked that self still exists in
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: r) { [weak self] (d, r, r) in

However, that could be completely pointless. What is the situation?
I can't see how a retain cycle could be created since everything in the closure is only within .items within the API singleton.

Yes, you need the capture list to avoid a retain cycle, but is there any reason not to use modern async/await?

@vadian thanks, TBSTBS, you realize I'm asking about line 7 of my code sample.  (Not the irrelevant example code at api.items).  (2) If so, I believe you but, I cannot see how it create a retain cycle in that case, I wonder if that could be explained?  (3) In answer to your last question, last time I checked async/await was a non-starter as it does not offer a realistic way to monitor progress.

To clarify you don't need to capture self if there is no code which refers to self, you should get a compiler warning in this case, however if blah is self.blah you do need it. …as it does not offer a realistic way to monitor progress. It does, there is a delegate parameter.

[To clarify you don't need to capture self if there is no code which refers to self] yup I know that :)

If you escape self as weak you have to write self?.blah, the non-optional syntax is [unowned self]. The closure can cause a retain cycle because it's @escaping

@vadian fair enough, you're saying "if you use self.x, then regardless, it can retain". It just seemed strange in the case of a data task (which eliminates itself) in a singleton (all of which are the same as "the app").  Anyway probably a lame question.  TY !

@vadian , how are you, just going back to the "use async/await" - "progress" issue.  if I'm not mistaken, getting actual progress when using the modern async/await system, is impractical to the point of being useless.  There are endless discussions on this, example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68276940  I wonder if you have any thoughts on this?  {If I'm not mistaken (a) there is no advantage, whatsoever, in any way, to the new async/await method over the ancient dataTask method, (b) it seems that the new method just uses the old method under the hood anyway fwiw (c) every codebase I'v

... e ever seen, and certainly for us, everyone just writes their own convenient wrapper for dataTask, depending on your style/needs/clients, and ... ironically it seems one would have to realistically do that anyway with the new async/await approach, heh!  So again I'm wondering your thoughts on this}

From the documentation of URLSessionTaskDelegate: If you create tasks with Swift’s async-await syntax, using methods like bytes(for:delegate:) and data(for:delegate:), you pass a delegate argument of this type. The delegate receives callbacks for things like task progress, while the call point awaits the completion of the task. You could use the bytes(for… API.

@vadian gotchya, but bytes#for if not mistaken is very slow.  using bytes#for, I guess we could put it this way, is a very low level solution. You have to build up your own sort of buffering / block handling / sensible file writing / whatever solution to deal with the incoming data as well as indeed making a usable progress report.  I have not yet seen a good "post on the internet!" where this is all done and I haven't bothered nor anyone I know, so I guess for that reason, well, as of today it's not usable by me anyways, I suppose - !!

Please see my kind-of-offtopic answer.

unreal, thanks for that I will run some tests!  @vadian

I know that this is not a literal answer to the question, but I'd like to suggest an example how to use progress report with the async/await API
Run the code in a Playground and replace https://example.com/pathToLargeFile.zip with a real URL pointing to a large file
class ProgressTest : NSObject, URLSessionTaskDelegate {
    
    private var progressObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?
    
    func load() async {
        do {
            let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/pathToLargeFile.zip")!
            let (data, _ ) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url, delegate: self)
            print("complete")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didCreateTask task: URLSessionTask) {
        progressObservation = task.progress.observe(\.fractionCompleted) { progress, value in
            print("progress: ", progress.fractionCompleted)
        }
    }
}


Task {
    let test = ProgressTest()
    await test.load()
}


that does work!  {aside: it has exactly the same "apple's oldest bug" where reporting is wrong in the early stage when waiting for the first byte, so structly in that regard there's no improvement over using age-old dataTask#with#completion !)  I'm totally confused now, I don't know if that suffers the same "runs much slower" issue as described here:  https://khanlou.com/2021/10/download-progress-with-awaited-network-tasks/    I will try to test it

The "engine" is still old URLSession, Apple added just the async/await APIs. Note that my suggestion uses the standard data(from: API unlike the linked article.

TY. Right, anyway the bottom line is you've done it.  I think I might just add async/await to our already long-developed wrapper, know what I mean.  And now back to the olympics!

I ticked this for the sake of tidyness!
