# Maximum Concurrent Http connections per host, Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, nsurlsession, afhttpsessionmanager

I'd like to increase the maximum concurrent connections per host in Swift, which is limited to 4 by default in iOS.

I'm using **Alamofire**.

- I've tried to increase the HTTPMaximumConcurrentPerHost to 50.
- I've tried for in loop method and still limited.
- Also tried to wrap the url request into an operation queue and still limited connections.

I've seen a library written in Obj-C tells that they use more than 4 connection at same time per host, but I don't program Obj-C to know if  it is real or not. 
[Library on Github](https://github.com/Lightstreamer/utility-ThreadPool-ios)

**Is there a solution which uses more concurrent connections per host?**

> Apple says that this limit is per session, so this limit can be
>   exceeded using multiple session per whole application

**How that can be achieved ?**

> *I've tested my internet speed and server response by **Charles** and it was 250 Req/Second, when using above methods in simulator it was 22 Req/Second.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021896/nsurlsession-concurrent-requests-with-alamofire?rq=1):

```
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
configuration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 50
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30
let manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
```

Bear in mind that unless the framework uses asynchronous IO (and I don't think that NSURLSession does) that you are limited by the number of cores in the processor as to how many threads you can be executing concurrently.  The answer I linked above suggests wrapping the requests in `NSOperation` so that you can manage the concurrency more granularly with an `NSOperationQueue`.