# Swift: OperationQueue - wait for asynchronous calls to finish before starting next (have maximum of 2 URLRequests running at a time)

Tags: swift, nsurlrequest

tl;dr I have an OperationQueue and I want to have two operations running at the time. Those operations download something asynchronously hence they all get triggered at once instead of running one after another.

I fill a table of very large images by doing doing the following for each of the images:

```
public func imageFromUrl(_ urlString: String) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if let imageData = data as Data? {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.setImageData(imageData)
                }
            }
        });

        task.resume()
    }
```

calling it like `imageView.imageFromUrl(...)`.

On slower internet connections, the calls stack and it starts loading every image at once. The user then has to wait for the downloads to "fight" each other and is staring at a blank screen for a while before the images all appear at once (more or less). It would be a much better experience for the user if one image appeared after another.

I thought about queuing up the items, downloading the first of the list, drop it from the list and call the function recursively like this:

```
func doImageQueue(){

    let queueItem = imageQueue[0]

    if let url = NSURL(string: (queueItem.url)) {
        print("if let url")
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            print("in")
            if let imageData = data as Data? {
                print("if let data")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    queueItem.imageView.setImageData(imageData)
                    self.imageQueue.remove(at: 0)
                    if(self.imageQueue.count>0) {
                        self.doImageQueue()
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

This does load the images one after another, by I think it's a waste of time not to have at least 2 requests running at a time. Making my current implementation handle 2 images at the same time would result in big spaghetti code so I've looked into Swift's `OperationQueue`.

I would do

```
let queue = OperationQueue()
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 2

for (all images) {
    queue.addOperation {
        imageView.imageFromUrl(imageURL
    }
}
```

But this also triggers all the calls at once, probably due to the fact that the requests run asynchronously and the method call ends before waiting for the image to be downloaded. How can I deal with that? The app will also run on watchOS, maybe there is a library for this already but I don't think this should be too hard to achieve without a library. Caching isn't a concern.

Comment: You are dealing with asynchronous tasks, so you either need to make them behave synchronously with semaphores or the like (as suggested by rmaddy below) or you need to make an asynchronous custom `Operation` subclass as outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/a/32322851/1271826 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021896/nsurlsession-concurrent-requests-with-alamofire/27022598#27022598.

Comment: Completely unrelated, but why create `NSURL` and `NSURLRequest`, to only cast them to the native `URL` and `URLRequest` objects? Just create those objects from the start. Don't use those `NS` classes in your code.

Comment: Rob you are right, copied this code and added my bits to it because I was more concerned about getting it to work in first instance but without you I wouldn't have noticed, will defo change it. Thanks for bringing it to my attention, I appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code with the operation queue and your original `iamgeFromUrl` method are all you need if you make one small change to `imageFromUrl`. You need to add a couple lines of code to ensure that `imageFromUrl` doesn't return until the download is complete.

This can be done using a semaphore.

```
public func imageFromUrl(_ urlString: String) {
    if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            semaphore.signal()
            if let imageData = data as Data? {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.setImageData(imageData)
                }
            }
        });

        task.resume()
        semaphore.wait()
    }
}
```

As written now, the `imageFromUrl` will only return once the download completes. This now allows the operation queue to properly run the 2 desired concurrent operations.

Also note the code is modified to avoid using `NSURL` and `NSURLRequest`.

Comment: This is the correct answer and you are awesome, thanks for that!!! Perfect solution.

Comment: Not perfect! Can cause issues (too many spawned threads) when more than a few images will be downloaded concurrently.