# How to interrupt Thread.sleep. Alternatives?

Tags: swift, timer, nsoperationqueue, operationqueue

I have implemented an Operation on an OperationQueue.

```
override func main() {
    super.main()
    if isCancelled {
        return
    }
    if member.memberType == .timed {
        triggerRestEvent(duration: member.restDuration)
    }
    if isCancelled {
        triggerEndEvent()
    }
}
```

The `triggerRestEvent` function is actually calling `Thread.sleep`. Once the sleep has expired we then check `isCancelled`.

Is there a way to interrupt `Thread.sleep` when `isCancelled` is toggled on?

**Alternative - RunLoop**

The docs for RunLoop suggest a while loop around the function `run` with a custom condition in the while loop. But how would I setup a timer to toggle the while loops execution? And apparently using a while loop in this way, for this purpose, is an antipattern these days?

Comment: Why do you need (or what for) Thread.sleep?

Comment: `Thread.sleep` ***is an antipattern these days***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Thread.sleep` is non-cancelable and blocks a thread. And spinning on a `RunLoop` is inefficient. That having been said, there are a few alternatives:

1. Nowadays, to manage dependencies between asynchronous tasks, we would reach for Swift concurrency’s `Task` rather than `Operation`. In Swift concurrency, we have [`Task.sleep`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/3862701-sleep), which, unlike `Thread.sleep`, is cancelable and does not block the thread.
2. If you want to stay within `OperationQueue` patterns, you would use an asynchronous custom `Operation` subclass (perhaps the `AsynchronousOperation` shown in either [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48104095/1271826) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021896/nsurlsession-concurrent-requests-with-alamofire/27022598#27022598)), and then you would use a timer. You could use a `DispatchSourceTimer`, or a `Timer`, or `asyncAfter` with a cancelable `DispatchWorkItem`. Which you choose really does not matter. The key is to ensure that the `cancel` implementation invalidates the `Timer` or cancels the `DispatchWorkItem` or `DispatchSourceTimer`, e.g.:

   ```swift
   class OneSecondOperation: AsynchronousOperation {
       weak var timer: Timer?

       override func main() {
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { [weak self] _ in
                   self?.finish()
               }
           }
       }

       override func cancel() {
           super.cancel()
           timer?.invalidate()
           finish()
       }
   }
   ```

   Note, the pattern whereby you periodically check `isCancelled` only applies if you have an existing loop. E.g., if you are doing some iterative calculation, for example, that is a very reasonable pattern. But if you are just waiting, the idea of introducing a loop merely to check `isCancelled` is inefficient. Instead, set up a timer and implement `cancel` method that cancels that timer, as shown above.

Either way, you want implementation that does not block a thread and can be canceled. With `Operation` subclass you have to implement that yourself. With Swift concurrency, you get that for free.